# Like button for android only works for Administrator of App

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-android-sdk

Facebook Like button on Android platform is working only for Administrator of App.
It does not even work for a test user. Please see following image showing like/sharing activity for Administrator and for all other users.

The review failed. the response from reviewer is "Your Open Graph action failed to publish on any of the Platforms you submitted. Make sure the action is working properly by publishing the action with a test user before resubmitting."

Where is the problem. How Can I make it work for all users?

[image: Like button for android only works for Administrator of App]

Comment: You need to submit your app for review, and add the "Native Like button" to the list of items in your submission (it's under Features, near the bottom of the list).

Comment: oh! Thanks a lot. Earlier I was submitting review for "Like". Now I submitted for "Native Like Button"

Lets wait for review to finish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to submit your app for review before you can use the like button publicly, just add the "Native Like button" to the list of items in your submission (it's under Features, near the bottom of the list).

Comment: your suggestion worked. Now Native Like button is approved. Many Thanks